# i should inheritance in django template html file

Tags: html, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i have two html file ,i should extends secend file from first file but it doesnt work

first file base.html

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Library{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="test">
        {% block test %}
            <h1>This page belongs to me.</h1>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

secend one booklist.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h3>Books</h3>
<div>
{% for book in books %}
    {% if book.available %}
        <p>{{ book.author }} wrote {{ book.title }}.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Forgot to add in your parent template

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

This is where the child template is going to be placed.
Your parent template should look like this (for example):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Library{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="test">
        {% block test %}
            <h1>This page belongs to me.</h1>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

<div class="myChildContentComesHere">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
</body>

</html>
```